# I am continuously getting a error when importing css file of the select to library in a react app

Tags: reactjs, sass, jquery-select2

I am using select2 library in my react app to add some drop downs. When i am importing  the css file it gives a error saying "you may need a appropriate loader to handle this file type".
so how can fix this error. In  my project i am using SCSS to style my components.

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IUu5.png)

My loader in webpack.config.js is like this

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another loader right before your scss loader

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
},
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!scss-loader'
},
```

Comment: Can you also edit your post to show your webpack loader and also make a comment showing the new error after updating your webpack to add the css loader

Comment: ya sure hold on

Comment: thanks dude. i figure it out . i have accidently replace the my loader withe css loader you have provided

Comment: One more thing kenneth Truong. after importing style sheet how can i style the the select2 dropdowns. I can't access to the select2 by using className or id to style it.

Comment: You probably have to add a wrapper `div` with a class and override the select2 dropdown's styles. Unless select2 has a way to customize their style. 

For example in render you wrap 
<div className="myClass">
   <select2>
</div>

.scss file or css file
.myClass <some select2 classes> { 
  // styles you want
}